# Action with viewmodel as parameter is not null despite optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

At the moment I am wondering about an unexpected behavior of action methods in ASP.NET Core. An action method with a viewmodel as an **optional** parameter is called without providing the optional parameter. The result is that the viewModel is **not** null. The default constructor of ViewModel is called instead. As far as I remember in ASP.NET MVC4 the default behavior is, that the parameter is null.

This is an example action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ViewModel viewModel = null)
{

}
```

Is there any way to change to the old behavior?